# Using pathlib in Google Colab: AttributeError: ‘PosixPath’ object has no attribute ‘ls’

Tags: python, pathlib

If I run the following code:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('data/mnist')
path.ls()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: ‘PosixPath’ object has no attribute ‘ls’
```

Looking at the Path class in pathlib, I find:

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Path:
            cls = WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else PosixPath
        self = cls._from_parts(args, init=False)
        if not self._flavour.is_supported:
            raise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"
                                      % (cls.__name__,))
        self._init()
        return self
```

I'm guessing this means it will run PosixPath instead, which is:

```
class PosixPath(Path, PurePosixPath):
    """Path subclass for non-Windows systems.

    On a POSIX system, instantiating a Path should return this object.
    """
    __slots__ = ()
```

Not too sure what this means.

And actually, I can't find Path.ls() at all in the pathlib source code. Does this make sense? The coding tutorial I'm following used it (on a windows machine).

Comment: Can you share the tutorial you are following?

Comment: https://youtu.be/CJKnDu2dxOE?t=5069 (with timestamp)

Comment: That's weird, and I suspect the notebook cells were edited without reexecuting them.

Comment: The notebook is missing just about every import it should need, too. Even the `from fastai import *` shouldn't actually load anything useful from `fastai` - you have to explicitly import submodules for that. `fastai`'s `__init__.py` doesn't load any submodules but `fastai.version`, and it doesn't define an `__all__` list.

Comment: Yeah, I even tried using `from fastai.imports import *`

Comment: The [data_block](https://docs.fast.ai/data_block.html) API of fastai implements its own Path (see bellow).

Answer (score 4):

If one reads the documentation of the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module one can confirm that, indeed, the class `Path` has no method `ls`. However, if your objective is to list files on a give directory, you could use the `glob` method like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

DIR = '.'
PATHGLOB = Path(DIR).glob('./*')
LS = [fil for fil in PATHGLOB]
```

I think this code snippet achieves the same that the code in your tutorial.

## EDIT:

The fastai module does implement the `ls` method like this:

```
Path.ls = lambda x: [o.name for o in x.iterdir()]
```

I think the observed behavior is the result of the import `*` in the Jupyter notebook of the tutorial. This can be corroborated with the following code snippet:

```
from fastai import data_block

path = data_block.Path('.')
path.ls()
```

Comment: Yeah, that is good! And I know how to get around the issue I'm having, but I wanted to figure out why someone can use ls() on the windows machine, and I can't seem to with Google Colab.

Comment: @JacquesThibodeau I have improved my answer. I believe the observed behavior is the result of the import `*` in the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: So, it works if I use `from fastai.vision import *`. It seems I need to specifically import one of the applications for it to work. I realized this because DataBunch wasn't working either until I imported `fastai.vision`. Not sure if this is a bug or not.